# Contradiction b/w Big bang theory and conservation of mass

Tags: conservation-laws, space-expansion, universe, mass-energy, big-bang

As per the conservation of mass, matter cannot be created or destroyed.

Doesn't this contradict the big bang theory? Like, it states that it all started from a single point. But seeing the massive size of the universe, isn't it weird that a single point held this much debris for the formation of planets, stars etc.?

Comment: *As per the conservation of mass* The sum of the masses of particles isn’t conserved. For example, electrons and positrons have mass, but they can annihilate into massless photons. The opposite can also occur, where photons create matter. Matter *can* be created and destroyed, and we don’t need a Big Bang to do it; we can observe it happening in particle accelerators.

Comment: Currently we are not even expecting a conservation of energy to hold on the scale of the entire universe. It's not even clear that the notion of energy makes any sense at that scale.